# PostgreSQL filter and order by array

Tags: arrays, postgresql, sql-order-by

I have a table with an arrays that I want to match against. The matching works by using the `&&` operator:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE data && ARRAY['foo','bar'];
id | data
---+----------
 1 | {foo}
 2 | {bar}
 6 | {bar,foo}
```

The next thing I want now, is also to sort them in the order they are in that array, something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE data && ARRAY['foo','bar'] ORDER BY data && ARRAY['foo','bar'];
id | data
---+----------
 1 | {foo}
 6 | {bar,foo}
 2 | {bar}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe something like `ORDER BY position( 'foo' in array_to_string(data, ',') ), position( 'bar' in array_to_string(data, ',') )`.

Comment: @Patrick `data` is a `TEXT[]` column.

Comment: @HannoBinder looks like a solution, but what if I do not know the length of the array I am comparing to. In my case, I am selecting that data first from another column/table.

Comment: @Patrick my mistake `col` should be `data`, I updated my question.

Comment: "I am selecting that data first from another column/table" -- Are you sure that arrays are the right way to store your data? Seems like otherwise a join could do what you need.

Comment: [WITH ORDINALITY](http://michael.otacoo.com/postgresql-2/postgres-9-4-feature-highlight-with-ordinality/) may also be helpful (see bottom of page).

Comment: @HannoBinder in this case, I don't think so. It is part of a larger system, where I have an array of values that need to be matched to another array. After matching, I need it to be sorted in the same way the elements are in the array. (It is part of a location-finding functionality, where I first check for room in location type 'foo', then in location type 'bar').

Comment: "I have an array of values that need to be matched to another array" - Sure, but what if you did not use arrays in the first place but stick to 1NF and have one row in some table per former array element?

Comment: @HannoBinder That is probably what I would have done if I had designed it this way from the start. Thing is, it is part of a larger system and changing the structure would imply possible (probable) other issues.

Answer (score 0):

this probably isn't best mode, but should work.

SELECT ... 
ORDER BY data && ARRAY['bar'], data && ARRAY['foo'];

or...

ORDER BY 'bar' = ANY(data) desc, 'foo' = ANY(data) desc;